# I can't get ViewPageIndicator to swipe

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, swipe, viewpagerindicator, android-holo-everywhere

i have created a new project and included the `HoloEveryWhere` library. Then I decided to add the `ViewPageIndicator`.
I copied all the code from `ViewPageIndicator` sample but it didn't work.
I tried using `SherlockFragment` but that didn't work either.
So I removed `HoloEveryWhere` from my project but apparently that wasn't the problem cause it still doesn't swipe.

edit:

this is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    />
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
```

you see, i just copied the two tags from the samples.
this is the main.java:

```
package com.example.test;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private static final String[] CONTENT = new String[] { "Recent", "Artists", "Albums", "Songs", "Playlists", "Genres" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new GoogleMusicAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    TabPageIndicator indicator = (TabPageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    indicator.setViewPager(pager);
}

class GoogleMusicAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public GoogleMusicAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return TestFragment.newInstance(CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length]);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
      return CONTENT.length;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: post your code otherwise it is not possible to answer

Comment: @SyedZahidAli is correct also check that you have added `ViewPageIndicator` jar to your build path ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your layout is the source of your difficulty.

If you are going to use `RelativeLayout`, you need to specify where the widgets inside the `RelativeLayout` go. By default, they all go in the upper-left corner, and later children (your `ViewPager`) float over top of earlier children (your `TabPageIndicator`) on the Z axis. Hence, with your current layout, the user cannot touch your `TabPageIndicator`.

Either switch to a `vertical` `LinearLayout` or use the appropriate attributes (e.g., `android:layout_below`) to organize your widgets in the `RelativeLayout` so that they do not overlap.

Hierarchy View is a useful tool for helping you identify this sort of problem.